# How you create a new Apps account using App Engine Admin console?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I have looked for links/pages to create one account but I cannot see anything related. Here it says that you can create an account https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pVZfdeky-ow/TO1SmipM2Y0J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to the Dashboard, then from the left-hand menu select "Application Settings", scroll down to the Domain Setup section and click "Add Domain...". You will see the link to signup on the right hand side.